# What abbreviations like "\\n", "\\r" can I use for DELETE?

Tags: linux, bash

actually I need a "\?" for deleting a character like pressing the delete key.
I want to use it in Linux bash in a CTF challenge...

Is there one? Where can I get a list of all ? combinations?

Thx

Comment: `man ascii` is a good start. Backspace is `\b`.

Comment: thx. Thats all i needed.

Comment: Are you sure you want backspace and not rubout? (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347882/what-is-readline-backward-delete-char-rubout)